# Resizing Canvas/UI elements to fit game view

Tags: user-interface, canvas, progress-bar

I recently downloaded an asset package with 3 different bars for health, mana and shield. I exported that project, and imported it into my game, and I know this has happened before but the canvas and the 3 bars that it contains in the top left are enormous, many many times bigger than the game view. 
I have researched and tried every setting I can find, but can only resize every individual element of the bars (background, bar, icon, text) separately in which case they move apart from each other, and even then changing the font does not resize the text to fit the resized elements. Furthermore, when I start the game the elements do resize a little on their own, but appear large, and to the left of the game view, and behind any other objects in the scene regardless of their Z position value.
I am really close to being able to use my game to make some good things, but this is really, really holding me up, and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bhxtfkyz97evzih/healthbarconundrum.jpg?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2brkattn2ep0ddr/healthbar%20conundrum.jpg?dl=0

Comment: The first pic is what it looks like when double clicking on any of the health bars in the heiarchy. The game is waaaaay down in the middle and is not even visible until zooming way in. The top red bar is what happens when you try to manually change the height and width of each individual element in the health bar in a complete fail of an attempt to properly resize it.
The second pic is inside the game view is in game view after pressing play.
Ideally I want them stuck to the top left of the screen, and if there was a 2 player it would be on the top right.
Thaaanks!  